# How to 'feed' data from data tab in other tabs based on criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ideally this file will take an Order number and based on certain column aspects feed it into the respective tab. (For Reference we will be taking data from a car repair shop to determine if the car being worked on has been scheduled for drop off, at the shop, or completed and left the shop.

For Example we will have an Order number for every Car we work on, this car will have a Date Started & date Completed. Based on these criteria it will take the Order Number and drop it into the correct Tab and the rest of the data will populate with xlookup (or up for something better to try). So as the life of the product is updated it flows to the appropriate tabs.

Data Tab --> Comprehensive List of all Cars(including cars not scheduled) --> Cars being worked on --> Completed Cars

I figured 90% of this can be solved using xlookup and IF statements but where I get stumped is how do I pull the specific Order Numbers into the respective tabs from the Data tab.

I am aware that I need to create a formula to check if a car has been scheduled for drop off vs it being finish so it doesn't find it's way into the complete tab but that should be easy once I am able to pull Order number's into the file.

Not Necessarily looking for an answer but some topics/videos to point me in the right direction:)

I have tried just pasting the data and xlookup the details from the Order Number but that just brings back the manual aspect of the workbook.

the way i am thinking about this is java terms would be:
If(order # = In Shop)
RO# Populates into "cars being Worked on" Tab

but for each tab

Am I going to need to use VBA/Macro to get the desired result or is there something simpler I am missing?

Not Necessarily looking for an answer but some topics/videos to point me in the right direction:)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build a VBA implementation, I'd look into using Power Query. I find Power Query to be a pretty low barrier tool as it has quite an intuitive UI and loads of material on the web.

This implementation would most likely have an input table on one tab and then the other tabs (WIP, Completed, etc.) would be connected to this input table.